# is it possible to browse the vuetify document site in the local environment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

The documentation site is on https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify, but you can start up the development server in your local environment and see it.
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify I cloned github itself, moved to the packages/docs directory, and ran the npm install command, but an error occurred.

Comment: *an error* you say. What you need is "a solution"